# Android spinner selecting same item twice

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I know this question already asked by many people but still i have quires. If i click that  same item in spinner itemonclicklisterner not triggered. I found some code in google. like

```
public class SpinnerTrigger extends Spinner {

public SpinnerTrigger(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
    ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
    super.setSelection(position, animate);
}

private void ignoreOldSelectionByReflection() {
    try {
        Class<?> c = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
        Field reqField = c.getDeclaredField("mOldSelectedPosition");
        reqField.setAccessible(true);
        reqField.setInt(this, -1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception Private", "ex", e);
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
    super.setSelection(position);
}

}
```

I created class with  this code. But my question is where i need to call this class.I mean from main activity where i need to call and which one i  need to call(ignoreOldSelectionByReflection  method or setSelection). I tried in google all are given this class but no one explained regarding this. So anyone help me to get out from this issue.

Comment: You have show here code of custom spinner class which is not solution of your query, so just use simple spinner in xml and implement it in main activity

Answer (score 1):

Case you couldn't find a solution for your problem:

If you don't need a custom spinner class than just forget it.

All you need to do is to select programmatically an item in your spinner (which differs from the already selected one) and than the second selection will be triggered. Common usage of spinners to add a "" at the top of the list in order to have an empty item as default selection. So it is a good idea to reset to selection index to that item (which is in 0 index position):

```
Spinner spinnerMyList = findViewById(R.id.spinnerMyList);
spinnerMyList.setSelection(0);
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score -3):

use this methd. this is work for me

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I have my code like this only. But while selecting same item second time it's not calling "spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener" itself. You have any other idea please let me know